# Android Paint - PorterDuffXfermode SRC_IN not working

Tags: android, porter-duff

i want to achieve a circular image affect using PorterDuffXfermode as per this article and image: [porterDuff tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/practical-image-porterduff-mode-usage-in-android-3b4b5d2e8f5f)

[image]

So i have destination circle which [is this](https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180724/ylj/kisspng-black-circle-black-and-white-clip-art-5b57e71c3a9e26.9145405015324874522401.jpg)

and i have a source image [which is this](https://www.fix.com/assets/content/15574/city-bike-riding-open-graph.png):

and i created a custom imageview and in the ondraw i was going to draw a circular image like the tutorial.  so my code for doing that looks like this:

```
    class ImageCutomView : ImageView {
        constructor(p0: Context) : super(p0)
        constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?) : super(p0, p1)
        constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?, p2: Int) : super(p0, p1, p2)


        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
            super.onDraw(canvas)
    val sideLengthY = measuredHeight
    val sideLengthX = measuredWidth
    val fullRect = Rect(0,0, sideLengthX,sideLengthY)
    if (canvas != null) {
            if (canvas != null) {
                val paint = Paint()

                val destination = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    context.resources,
                    R.drawable.black_circle
                )

                val source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    context.resources,
                    R.drawable.bikeriding
                )
                canvas.drawBitmap(destination, null, fullRect, paint)

 paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)

                canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, fullRect, paint)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Now the problem** is that it does not draw a circular image. here is how i been using the custom view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
>

    <com.example.mycustomVews.ImageCutomView
            android:id="@+id/red_star"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp" 
            android:background="@color/aqua_green"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but when it renders it looks like this:

[image]

What am i doing wrong. i tried all the porterDuff modes, nothing works.

Comment: What is the end result, show a image how you expect your final image to look??

Comment: should be circular image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to this question [PorterDuffXfermode DST_IN not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654322/porterduffxfermode-dst-in-not-working-as-expected)

He says that:

"Be careful though: it will work only in a transparent Bitmap or in layer. When you draw directly on screen, the destination is already filled by the window background."

You could also clip the canvas before and then fill the clipped canvas, so you would do in Java:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Path path = new Path();

    // IN CASE OF RECTANGLE
    path.addCircle(getWidth()/2f, getHeight()/2f, Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight())/2f, Path.Direction.CW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);


    // CENTERED POSITION, NOT SCALED BITMAP
    float l = (getWidth()-yourSourceBitmap.getWidth())/2f;
    float t = (getHeight()-yourSourceBitmap.getHeight())/2f;

    // DRAW INTO CLIPPED
    canvas.drawBitmap(yourSourceBitmap, l, t, null);


}
```

Comment: yes i could using a  clip path, but just wanted to know why porterduff mode was not working, thanks